# Let $A=(-1,0),B=(1,0), C$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ What is the locus of points $\{s\in\mathbb{R}^2:C$ lies on the angle bisector of $AsB$}?

Tags: geometry, triangles, locus

Let $A=(-1,0),\ B=(1,0),\ C$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ What (shape(s)) is the locus of points $L(C)=\{s\in\mathbb{R}^2:C$ lies on the angle bisector of $AsB$ } ?

Obviously the set $L$ depends on where $C$ is, which is why I've written $L$ as a function of $C.$

If $C$ is the midpoint of $AB$, or on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, it is not clear to me that $L= \{$ the perpendicular bisector of $AB\},$ because maybe $L$ contains more points. [Edit: Karan Elangovan has answered this part of the question.]

Comment: If $C$ lies on the line $AB$, say at $(c,0)$, then the locus is the circle on diameter $CC'$, where $C'=(1/c,0)$. This is an instance of the Apollonius circles.

Comment: If you want someone to get the full bounty, you should award it, or accept an answer. If you do nothing, only half will go to brainjam's answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me- I was planning on awarding it this morning, but got side-tracked.

Comment: I just didn't want half of the bounty to go to waste. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The locus you are asking about is a subset of a cubic curve called an Apollonian strophoid (or strophoid of Apollonius).

The curve is the set of points $S$ for which either the internal or bisector of the angle $\angle ASB$ passes through $C$.  (The external bisector is the line through $S$ perpendicular to the internal bisector.)  As the strophoid $\Sigma$ comes in from infinity, $C$ is on the internal bisector but, as $\Sigma$ goes past $A$, $C$ is on the external bisector until $\Sigma$ passes $B$ after which $C$ is back on the internal bisector all the way to infinity.  So your locus is actually the strophoid minus the section between $A$ and $B$.

A GeoGebra applet that demonstrates the strophoid can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/n5jexqyp).  The strophoid is blue, the external bisector is green. You can move $S$ and $C$.  (Unfortunately the $S$ will jump around if you modify any of the points.  This is annoying but harmless.)  The strophoid is built using mathlove's equation.

[image: strophoid]

There are two special cases where the cubic degenerates to a line $\ell$ and a circle $c$.   Both have been touched upon in other answers and comments for this question.

- when $C$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $B$, line $\ell$ is the perpendicular bisector and $c$ is the circumcircle of $A,B,C$.  For points $S$ on $c$ it is the external bisector that goes through $C$.  (Because, if $M$ is the midpoint of $A,B$ then the triangle $\triangle ECS$ is a right angle.
- when $C$ is on the line $AB$, line $\ell$ is the line $AB$ and $c$ is an Apollonian circle of the segment $AB$.

For more about strophoids see the following references.

[Gibert, *Apollonian strophoids*](https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k053.html) (part of a large catalog of so-called Triangle cubics)

[mathcurve.com (Strophoid page)](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/strophoid/strophoid.shtml)

[Stachel, *Strophoids, A Family Of Cubic Curves With Remarkable Properties*](https://www.geometrie.tuwien.ac.at/stachel/157_Strophoid_orig.pdf) (see Theorem 4).

Answer (score 3):

Let $C(a,b),s(x,y)$ where $y\not=0$.

Also, let $U(u,0)$ be the intersection point of the angle bisector with $x$-axis.

Then, we have
$$\begin{align}&sA:sB=AU:BU
\\\\&\iff (1-u)\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=(1+u)\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}
\\\\&\iff u=\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}\end{align}$$

So, $C$ is on the angle bisector ($sU$) if and only if
$$\begin{align}&b(x-u)=y(a-u)
\\\\&\iff (y-b)u=ay-bx
\\\\&\iff (y-b)\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}=ay-bx
\\\\&\iff (y-b)\bigg(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\bigg)
\\&\qquad\qquad=(ay-bx)\bigg(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\bigg)
\\\\&\iff (y-b-ay+bx)\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=(y-b+ay-bx)\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\end{align}$$

So, we have to have
$$(y-b-ay+bx)(y-b+ay-bx)\ge 0$$
under which we have
$$(y-b-ay+bx)^2\bigg((x+1)^2+y^2\bigg)=(y-b+ay-bx)^2\bigg((x-1)^2+y^2\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$\color{red}{bx^3-  a b x^2-  b x+(a^2 -b^2 +  1) x y -  a x^2 y +  b x y^2  -  a y^3+  a b y^2   -  a y     +  a b =0}$$

---

**Examples** :

- If $a=b=0$, then we get a line $x=0$.
- If $b=0$ with $a\not=0$, then we get a circle$$  \bigg(x-\frac{a^2+1}{2a}\bigg)^2 +  y^2   =\bigg(\frac{1-a^2}{2a}\bigg)^2$$under the condition that $-1\lt a\lt 1$ as jlammy commented.
- If $a=0$ with $b\not=0$, then we get a line $x=0$ or a circle $$x^2  +\bigg(y-\frac{b^2-1}{2b}\bigg)^2  =\bigg(\frac{b^2+1}{2b}\bigg)^2$$under the condition that $(y+bx-b)(y-bx-b)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Geometric Construction for $\boldsymbol{C}$ off the Axes**

Here is a geometric construction for the points of the locus.

We are given the points $A=(-1,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, and $C$. For any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, define
$$
\begin{align}
P&=\frac{A+C}2+\lambda\rho(C-A)\tag{1a}\\
Q&=\frac{B+C}2+\lambda\rho(B-C)\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
where $\rho(v)=v\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is $v$ rotated by $\frac\pi2$ counter-clockwise.

Then define two circles: one centered at $P$ passing through $A$ and $C$, and another centered at $Q$ passing through $B$ and $C$. Note that we are simply constructing two similar isosceles triangles: $\triangle APC$ and $\triangle BQC$.

By construction, both circles pass through $C$. Let the other point of  intersection of these circles be $D$.

[image]

By construction, $\angle APC=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\lambda}\right)=\angle BQC$. Thus, by the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle),
$$
\angle ADC=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\lambda}\right)=\angle BDC\tag2
$$

The construction above works because $A$ is outside the circle containing $B$ and $B$ is outside the circle containing $A$. This construction also works when $A$ is inside the circle containing $B$ and $B$ is inside the circle containing $A$

[image]

Again, $\angle APC=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\lambda}\right)=\angle BQC$. Thus, by the Inscribed Angle Theorem,
$$
\angle ADC=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\lambda}\right)=\angle BDC\tag3
$$

However, when only one of $A$ or $B$ is inside the circle containing the other, we have the following situation

[image]

Note that by the Inscribed Angle Theorem, $\angle BDC=\frac12\angle BQC$; however, $\angle ADC=\pi-\frac12\angle APC$.

$\angle ADC$ becomes supplementary to half its associated central angle, $\angle APC$, when $D$ passes through $A$; that is when $A$ changes whether it is inside or outside of the circle containing $B$. This happens when
$$
\lambda=\lambda_A\equiv\frac{(A-C)\cdot(B-A)}{2\rho(A-C)\cdot(B-C)}\tag4
$$

$\angle BDC$ becomes supplementary to half its associated central angle, $\angle BQC$, when $D$ passes through $B$; that is when $B$ changes whether it is inside or outside of the circle containing $A$. This happens when
$$
\lambda=\lambda_B\equiv\frac{(C-B)\cdot(B-A)}{2\rho(A-C)\cdot(B-C)}\tag5
$$

Which angle, $\angle ADC$ or $\angle BDC$, is supplementary to half its associated central angle switches when $D$ passes through $C$; that is, when the circles are internally tangent. This does not happen when the circles are externally tangent since then neither $A$ nor $B$ is inside the circle containing the other.

If we set
$$
\begin{align}
\mu&=\frac{(A-C)\cdot(B-C)}{\rho(A-C)\cdot(B-C)}\tag{6a}\\[3pt]
\sigma&=\operatorname{sign}(\rho(A-C)\cdot(B-C))\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
then the circles are internally tangent when
$$
\lambda=\frac{\mu-\sigma\sqrt{\mu^2+1}}2\tag7
$$
and externally tangent when
$$
\lambda=\frac{\mu+\sigma\sqrt{\mu^2+1}}2\tag8
$$
Here is an animation of $D$ (red point) traversing the locus of points (blue curve) where $C$ lies on the bisector of $\angle ADC$. The red curve is where one or the other inscribed angles is supplementary to half of its associated central angle.

[image]

---

**Locus for $\boldsymbol{C}$ on the Axes**

If $C$ is on the $y$-axis, then the locus is all of the $y$-axis except $C$.

If $C$ is on the $x$-axis, then the locus is all of the $x$-axis with the segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and $C$ removed.

If $C=(0,0)$ then the locus is the union of the $x$-axis and $y$-axis with the segment of the $x$-axis from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ removed.

Comment: Amazing diagrams and animation.

Comment: @robjohn Which application has been used for drawing and animation?

Comment: I used Mathematica 11.3 for all of the drawings and animation in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$.

$C$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, hence $AC = BC$

$\angle AsC = \angle BsC$

$sC$ is common.

Hence either the angles $\angle sCA$ and $\angle sCB$ are equal or supplementary. If they're supplementary, then $ACB$ is a straight line, meaning $C$ is the midpoint of $AB$. We will consider this case at the end. Otherwise though, we have $\angle ACs = \angle BCs$, and so $\triangle ACs \equiv \triangle BCs$, so $As = Bs$, so $s$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, so $L$ = the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, as required.

Finally consider the case that $C$ is the midpoint of $BC$, and the angles are supplementary.

$$ \frac{\sin\angle sBC}{sC} = \frac{\sin\angle BsC}{BC} \text{(Sine law)}$$
$$ = \frac{\sin\angle AsC}{AC} \text{(AC = BC})$$
$$ = \frac{\sin\angle sAC}{sC} \text{(Sine Law)}$$

So we have $\sin\angle sBC = \sin\angle sAC$, so the two angles are either equal or supplementary. Since they are angles of a triangle, they cannot be supplementary, so they are equal, so $\triangle sAB$ is isoceles with base $AB$, so $As = sB$, so again we have that $s$ lies on the perpendicular bisector, as required.

So **yes**, the only points in $L$ are those on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this covers only the cases where $C$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$?

Comment: Yes, this only covers that case. Though isn't your question only about that case?

Comment: Nowhere in my question do I restrict $C$ to be on the perpendicular bisector of $AB.$ $C$ Could be anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were only thinking about perpendicular bisector since in the last paragraph you said it wasn't clear to you why L would be the perpendicular bisector in that case.

Comment: Like I say, you've answered *that part* of the question. But the main question is the title.